# How do I get all possible combinations of a list to put into a dictionary, such as (a,b) and (b,a)?

Tags: python, dictionary, collections, python-itertools

I have an issue with my code:

```
 from collections import Counter
 from collections import defaultdict
 from itertools import combinations

 def findPairs(pair_counts, n): 

      
      pair_counts = dict() 
      count = Counter(combinations(n, 2))

      for key, value in count.items():
          pair_counts[key] = value
      print(pair_counts)


 nums = [2,3,7]
 #n = len(nums)
 findPairs(pair_counts, nums)
```

It gives an output of:

`{(2, 3): 1, (2, 7): 1, (3, 7): 1}`

BUT I want it to give an output that looks more like:

`{(2, 3): 1, (2, 7): 1, (3, 7): 1, (3,2):1, (7,2):1, (7,3):1)}`

Thanks in advance

Comment: you need `itertools.permutations` instead of `combinations`

Comment: As @AnkurSaxena said in this case permutations is needed where we do care about the order of the values as in combinations 321 and 123 are the same and only one is used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments, you need `permutations` instead of `combinations` from `itertools`. Below code works. And if your aim is to simply get a dictionary of count, you can simply do `dict(Counter(...))` to convert it into dict.
Also, removed some unnecessary code lines.

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import permutations

def findPairs(n): 
    ###
    pair_counts = dict() 
    count = dict(Counter(permutations(n, 2)))
    print(count)


nums = [2,3,7]
findPairs(nums)

# Output
# {(2, 3): 1, (2, 7): 1, (3, 2): 1, (3, 7): 1, (7, 2): 1, (7, 3): 1}
```

Comment: AWW thank you everyone!  I am going to look over itertools some more.

Answer (score 0):

Use permutation instead of combination

from itertools import permutations
count = Counter(permutations(n, 2))